# Composing ASP.NET Web form pages with react

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, webforms, components, integration

Does anyone know a way to compose pages made in ASP.NET WEB Form with react?

For example, I have this code that I got from this project: [https://github.com/xabikos/ReactjsWebForms](https://stackoverflow.com)

**Example.jsx:**

```
var ExampleComponent = class Example extends React.Component { 
    componentDidMount() { 
        console.log("Componente montado"); 
    } 
    handleClick1() { 
        console.log("Funcion 1") 
    } 
    handleClick2() { 
        console.log("Funcion 2") 
    } 
    handleClick3() { 
        console.log("Funcion 3") 
    } 
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example"> 
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleClick1 }>Left</button> 
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button> 
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary">Right</button> 
            </div> 
            ) 
    } 
}
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="IntegracionReactWebForms._Default" %> 
 
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
  <asp:Literal ID="PageContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
  <asp:Literal ID="ExampleComponent" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using React; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Optimization; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
 
namespace IntegracionReactWebForms 
{ 
    public partial class _Default : Page 
    { 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            var env = AssemblyRegistration.Container.Resolve<IReactEnvironment>(); 
            var objectModel = new { user = "React User" }; 
            var componentModel = new { hola = "Hello mate" }; 
            var exampleComponent = env.CreateComponent("ExampleComponent", componentModel); 
            var reactComponent = env.CreateComponent("PageContent", objectModel); 
 
            ExampleComponent.Text = exampleComponent.RenderHtml(); 
            PageContent.Text = reactComponent.RenderHtml(); 
             
        } 
    } 
}
```

When loading the page, the components are created perfectly, **but they lack functionality** in the case of the **onClick and the componentDidMount() function does not work**, and the integration is very difficult.

I have tried everything but there is hardly any documentation.